# Django Python ... Updating multiple elements in database

Tags: python, django

AoA,
    I know the question is silly, but I am stuck here

here is the code...

```
nq = Notifications.objects.filter(userid__iexact=q)
    for string in nq:
            string.markType = "Read"
    results = Notifications.objects.filter(Q(userid__iexact=q)).order_by('-id')
```

but the markType failed to set to "Read" ... why?

Comment: You never called `string.save()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to save the object after changing it:

```
nq = Notifications.objects.filter(userid__iexact=q)
for string in nq:
    string.markType = "Read"
    string.save()
results = Notifications.objects.filter(Q(userid__iexact=q)).order_by('-id')
```

Comment: I told you that it was a silly question
thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the fact that you forgot to save your object it is recommended to use [`queryset.update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) method here, it is going to be faster than your current approach. But in case you've overrided the `save` method then don't use it.:

```
Notifications.objects.filter(userid__iexact=q).update(markType = "Read")
```